# What is the difference between Bilinear function and Bilinear form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am going through a textbook on Matrix Algebra and I am not able to understand the difference between the two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bilinear function is a function $U\times V\to W$ satifying some identities, with $U,V, W$ being vectorspaces. A bilinear form is a function $V\times V\to k$, where $k$ is the field.